# passing name with & to another webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have a client name. `e.g: D&G.`

This names are passed to another Webpage. for example:

```
http://abc.com/test.aspx?client=D&G
```

When I retrieve the first `query[0]` in another Webpage, I only get `client=D` without `&G`

How can I fix the problem of **passing** names including `&`?.

Should I replace `&` with a special character before passing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Server.UrlEncode("D&G")` to encode it on server.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `%26`.

The `&` character has been URL encoded (percent encoded) as `%26`.

I add this link for you , it's very interessant, encoding of all specific caracters

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/